# Evaluating a limit using Squeeze Theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Consider a function $f (x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

$$
\left|f(x) - \frac{7^2 + 5x|x|+2}{x^2+16}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x^2}
$$

for all $x\neq0$. Calculate: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to −\infty} f(x) $.

Considerations:

> If $x \to \infty$ then we can consider $|x| = x$
>
> If $x \to -\infty$ then we can consider $|x| = -x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac{5x|x|}{x^2} + \cdots= \begin{cases} -5 & \text{   if  } x = \infty\\ 5 & \text{ if  } x = -\infty\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've answered the question yourself already. Let
$$
g(x) = \frac{7^2+5x\lvert x\rvert + 2}{x^2+16}
$$
Your statement above says $g(x)-1/x^2 \le f(x) \le g(x) + 1/x^2 $.

If $x$ is big, then $f(x)$ will be close to $\lvert x \rvert$.